# How can i add scan port ip

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

i coding scan server and client with scan all ip 
i use sockets / C 
but i don't understand how to add scan port for one of ip in struct 
i have a problem in scan port 
i have a wrong display he don't display any open
the probleme is nothing display any port open in server .
i can't found any solution 
i need help

```
#include <netdb.h> 
#include "stdio.h"
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr 

// Driver function 
int main() 
{ 
        int sockfd, connfd, len ,start , end,err;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 
        struct sockaddr_in addr_remote;
    char ips[2][20];
    char hostname[30];

    // socket create and verification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
    printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) { 
    printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

    // Now server is ready to listen and verification 

    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) { 
    printf("Listen failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("Server listening..\n"); 
    len = sizeof(cli); 

    // Accept the data packet from client and verification 
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&addr_remote, &len); 
    if (connfd < 0) { 
    printf("server acccept failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("server acccept the client...\n"); 
    strcpy(ips[i], inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr));
    }

    // Display Ip 
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("%s \n",ips[i]);}


    // Scan PORT

        //Get the hostname to scan
        printf("Enter hostname or IP : ");
        gets(hostname);

        //Get start port number
        printf("Enter start port number : ");
        //To Handle the Input
        int data;
        data = scanf("%d",&start);

        //Get end port number
        printf("Enter end port number : ");
        int data2 = scanf("%d" , &end);
        int j;
         //Start the port scan loop
            printf("Starting the portscan loop : \n");
            for( j = start ; j <= end ; j++)
            {
            //Fill in the port number
            servaddr.sin_port = htons(j);

            //Connect using that socket and sockaddr structure

            err =connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
            if( err < 0 )
            {
            //printf("%s %-5d %s\r" , hostname , i, strerror(errno));
            fflush(stdout);
            }
            //connected
            else
            {
            printf("%-5d open\n", j);
            }
        }

    // After chatting close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}
```

Comment: If the peer does not answer, the `connect()` call blocks quite long until the connect timeout is reached. Is that your problem?

Comment: yes he don't display port open of adress

Answer (score 0):

There's not only the states "open" and "closed", but also "filtered", when the peer does not respond at all to a connect request. This might happen, when the host isn't reachable at all, or when a certain port or portrange is dropped due to packet filter rules.

You can either wait for the `connect()` to timeout (which might be several minutes), or you switch to non-blocking connects:

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Now, the `connect()` call will return immediately and you can call `select()` or `poll()` on the file descriptor with an arbitrary timeout to speed up scanning.

Furthermore, you could scan several ports in parallel this way, which speeds up the total scanning time significantly.

However, really efficient scanners operate on raw sockets creating SYN packets and parsing the replies.

Comment: i am sorry bu i don't undertsand anything :( , how can add scan port in this code ?